# Okta configuration to login with user alias

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, okta

I am using Okta to authenticate the users on my application

https://www.okta.com/

right now when I am consuming the okta API to authenticate it allows me, however the authentication must be with the email like this:

test@test.com

But I would like to log in with an alias like this: test123 or whatever different to the email.

Do you know if is there any way to do that or definitively is there any limitation in the okta service?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you allow your login attribute to be in non-email format. "Directory" -> "Profile Editor" -> "Okta" -> "login" -> "Format restrictions"